# Отбор значений по столбам в сводной таблице

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, pivot

У меня есть следующий dataframe:

```
               Doly
Num_clusters    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
ID            
 a              0    0    0   0.1   0    0    0
 b              0   0.1  0.9   0    0    0    0
 c              0    0    0    0   0.1   0    0
 d              0.4  0.3  0    0   0.3   0    0
```

Мне нужно пройтись по всем столбцам 0-6 и найти только те строки (ID), у которых:
1) хотя бы в одной ячейке значение больше или равно 0.4,
2) тех, у которых два и более раза встречается больше 0.4
3) не вошедшие по условию 1 и 2
Т.е. создать отдельные 3 таблица из одной.

Я пробовала через цикл, но не знаю как обращаться к строке где ID=a и его значениям в Яцейках 0-6.

Comment: Вопрос в том `"как обращаться к строке где ID=a и его значениям в Яцейках 0-6."` или вы ожидаете решение для всех трех пунктов (в этом случае стоит привести пример результирующей таблицы)? В DataFrame используется `multi-level columns`?

Comment: @MaxU В качестве результата ожидается пример хотя бы одной таблицы либо пример как обращаться в цикле к каждому значению в столбцах 0-6 для одного ID. DataFrame - результат работы команды 'pivot_table', используется 'multi-level columns'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

Исходный DF:

```
In [51]: df
Out[51]:
   Doly
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6
ID
a   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.4  0.0
b   0.0  0.1  0.9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
c   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.0
d   0.4  0.3  0.0  0.0  0.3  0.5  0.6
```

Строки где хотя бы в одной ячейке значение больше или равно 0.4:

```
In [52]: mask1 = df["Doly"].ge(0.4).any(axis=1)

In [53]: mask1
Out[53]:
ID
a     True
b     True
c    False
d     True
dtype: bool

In [54]: df[mask1]
Out[54]:
   Doly
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6
ID
a   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.4  0.0
b   0.0  0.1  0.9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
d   0.4  0.3  0.0  0.0  0.3  0.5  0.6
```

Строки у которых два и более раза встречается больше 0.4:

```
In [55]: mask2 = df["Doly"].ge(0.4).sum(axis=1) > 1

In [56]: mask2
Out[56]:
ID
a    False
b    False
c    False
d     True
dtype: bool

In [57]: df[mask2]
Out[57]:
   Doly
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6
ID
d   0.4  0.3  0.0  0.0  0.3  0.5  0.6
```

Строки не вошедшие по условию 1 и 2:

```
In [62]: mask3 = ~(mask1 | mask2)

In [63]: mask3
Out[63]:
ID
a    False
b    False
c     True
d    False
dtype: bool

In [64]: df[mask3]
Out[64]:
   Doly
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6
ID
c   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.0
```